# Input outline css

Tags: javascript, css

I have some problems with mine design.
I'm trying to remove outline from my input, but nothing is working as expected. I'm using antd and this is how my code looks for input:

```
& .ant-input {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.4);
    padding-top:10px;
    border:none;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    border-color: rgba(44, 52, 64, 0.1);
    border-radius: 0px;
    transition: 2s border-color;
    outline: none;


    &:focus{
      outline: none;
      background: transparent;
      &::placeholder{
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.91);
        transition: 2s border-color;
        border-color: rgba(44, 126, 250, 1);
      }
    }
    &:hover {
      background: transparent;
    }

    &:-webkit-autofill,
    &:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
    &:-webkit-autofill:focus {
      border-bottom: 2px solid;
      border-color: rgba(44, 52, 64, 0.4);
      -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff;
      transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
```

I have live demo, can I post it here?

Comment: you can definitely post live demos here!

Comment: I have see JSFiddle being used here (as an example) - but with [some guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358213/12567365). I assume this is still current.

Comment: are you sure it's `outline` you're trying to remove and not `border`?

Comment: This is demo http://63897cc9.ngrok.io/contact

Comment: The demo is not working

Comment: maybe you can post here the HTML as well